# Android, HttpPost for WCF

Tags: java, android, wcf

I'm trying to use httpost to get data from our WCF webservice

If the webservice function is without params , something like List getAllMessages()

I'm getting the List in json, no problem here

The tricky part is when the function needs to get argument
let's say Message getMessage(string id) 
when trying to call this kind of functions I get error code 500

The working code is:

```
public String GetAllTitles()
 {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
            "http://www.xxx.com/Service/VsService.svc/GetAllTitles");

    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        return readHttpResponse(response);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

this code works great for functios without arguments..
I took this code and changed it to:

```
 public String SearchTitle(final String id)
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                   "http://www.xxx.com/Service/VsService.svc/SearchTitle");

        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        NameValuePair data = new BasicNameValuePair("id",id);
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(data);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            return readHttpResponse(response);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

The function header in thr webservice is:

```
 [OperationContract]
public TitleResult SearchTitle(string id)
{
    Stopwatch sw = LogHelper.StopwatchInit();
    try
    {
        TitleManager tm = new TitleManager();
        Title title = tm.TitleById(id);
        sw.StopAndLog("SearchTitle", "id: " + id);
        return new TitleResult() { Title = title };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        sw.StopAndLogException("SearchTitle", ex, "id: " + id);
        return new TitleResult() { Message = ex.Message };
    }
}
```

Anyone can see what am I missing?

Thanks, I'm breaking my head over this one.

Comment: Did u try with Get instead of Post?

Comment: No, as i understand it wont work with Get

Answer (score 0):

List isn't json,
try

```
String data = "{ id : \"" + id + "\" }";
```

Don't forget to set Content-Length to `data.length`.

Comment: How can i put String data inside  httppost.setEntity ?

Comment: i dont know exactly how, cuz i dont do android, but as a web programmer i 1st thing i saw is that u send data-type json but the actual data isnt json...